# How to adjust content on different screen sizes in react native

Tags: react-native, user-interface

I am using two different screens for a page but its not responsive.
I have used flex and percentage(%) to adjust margin but did not work for me.
Here is screenshot what actually my screens look like. [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nmhk0.jpg)

Comment: Check this link maybe it helps :https://medium.com/react-native-training/build-responsive-react-native-views-for-any-device-and-support-orientation-change-1c8beba5bc23

Comment: I have tried it, it is just for percentage. But i want my screens to be responsive on different screens using flex and percentage.

Comment: Using react native dimensions [https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions ] you can get screen width & height. Try to customize style using that. if not share you code.